# Flurry ads aren't showing

Tags: android, video, flurry, interstitial

I have integrated Flurry ads and they work if I test with my smartphone connected to my computer, then Run and Run on my device.

The problem comes when I try to compile it with the option: android tools -> export signed app package

It compiles perfectly but the app is 1 MB lighter and when I install this apk somewhere else, adverts aren't showing. I've tested it with all kind of adverts. Google adverts work perfectly in two compiling methods but Flurry.com adverts do not.

I've followed all their guides but still doesn't work.

### edit:

proguard-project.txt

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose

-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
   public *;
}

-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); 
}



# Google Play Services library
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
  protected Object[][] getContents(); 
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
  public static final *** NULL; 
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class * 
-keepclassmembernames class * {
  @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *; 
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final ** CREATOR;
}
#If you are using the Google Mobile Ads SDK, add the following:
# Preserve GMS ads classes
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *;
} 
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**


#If you are using the InMobi SDK, add the following:
# Preserve InMobi Ads classes 
-keep class com.inmobi.** { *;
} 
-dontwarn com.inmobi.**
#If you are using the Millennial Media SDK, add the following:
# Preserve Millennial Ads classes
-keep class com.millennialmedia.** { *;
} 
-dontwarn com.millennialmedia.**
```

Comment: Could be an issue with ProGuard config, maybe it's stripping out Flurry classes?

Comment: I don't know.. check my proguard (editing)

Comment: Hmm, looks ok to me.

Comment: try this trick preserve classes that have flurry implementations in them..If `MainActivity` has it preserve it..and try again and see the results

Comment: I'm very noob in this issure about flurry and proguard, could you explain better your answer?